# How to write the following regex

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio

code before >>>

```
dateTime1 = new DateTime(2015, 5, 24);

line2 ( some code)...;

line3 ( some code)...;

DateTimePicker.Value = dateTime1;
```

Code after regex >>>

```
line1 ---> ( will be cleared)

line2 ---> ( some code)...;

line3 ---> ( some code)...;

DateTimePicker.Value = new DateTime(2015, 5, 24);
```

I tried this as search pattern

```
( ^:b*dateTime[:d]{.+}\n{.+}\n{.+}\ndateTime[:d];$ )
```

but no result

Comment: Its not clear from your question what you are trying to match? give some sample expected matches?

Comment: Do you want to inline `dateTime1` or just delete the `dateTime1 = new DateTime(2015, 5, 24);` line?

Comment: It's a find replace regex. I want to combine line1 with line4 to avoid code repetition.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
            string input =
                "dateTime1 = new DateTime(2015, 5, 24);" +

                "line2 ( some code)...;" +

                "line3 ( some code)...;" +

                "DateTimePicker.Value = dateTime1;";

            string pattern = "(?'line1'[^;]*);(?'line2'[^;]*);(?'line3'[^;]*);(?'line4'[^;]*)";

            Regex expr = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);
            string output = expr.Replace(input, "${line2};${line3};${line1};");
​
```